# Textarea needs to keep formatting when sent through POST request

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form on a website that is then sent through to another page, this all works perfectly except I need the textarea to keep its text on different lines. Below is the code for my textarea and the post request that is on the other page.

```
<textarea name="Info" placeholder="Enter what you did there here" cols="75" rows="7"></textarea>

$Body = "<br>" . $_POST["Info"];
```

And when I submit the form it takes the textarea which has text on multiple lines and then just puts it all on one line.

Comment: Line feeds are ignored when HTML is rendered. If you want to preserve them , you will need to replace them with <br /> tags when rendered or stored.

Comment: @Fred: This is way off topic, but I couldn't find another way to say this: I want to thank you for all the help and constructive advice I see you offering to so many people.

Comment: @SloanThrasher You're most welcome, and thanks.